# On window load run one function, after 10seconds run another (setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to create an interval or timeout for two colors. On page load, I wish for my first function greyColor to run, until after 10seconds, I wish for my redColor to run, replacing that color.

I can show below what I've tried, but I think it's very wrong. I believe I need some type of clear on the grey timeout once the red timeout needs to run? Open for any suggestions! Thanks!

Edit: The example below is not the actual project, the code for it is rather complex. What we are trying to do is as the browser loads the the circles should be grey and after 10seconds changes to be red.

### Current idea

```
let red = "{% static "main_platform/media/red_circle.png" %}";
let grey = "{% static "main_platform/media/grey_circle.png" %}";    
let timeout;

    function greyColor() {
        timeout = setTimeout(get_color, 500);
        return timeout;
    }

    function redColor() {
        timeout = setTimeout(get_color: 10000);
        return timeout;
    }

    function get_color(choice) {
        if (greyColor()) {
            return grey;
        } else if(redColor) {
            return red;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but your code doesn't make any sense, you are not changing any color, and instead I see *"{% static "main_platform/media/red_circle.png" %}"*, and I assume it's a path for an image of red circle so that has no relation to changing the color, but the image instead, and can you post a live version including your HTML code

Comment: I know it does not make sense..I'm trying to make it make sense, perhaps don't look at the code but rather the description of what I'm trying to do. I've edited with a comment. :)

Comment: Ok, but you said I want the color to be gray when window loads, then why to wait exactly half a second to do that? instead of an event listener to `onload`

Comment: No reason, mostly because I didn't know how else to make it execute fast, I tried 0 but wasnt sure that would work. So, you suggest it all being in an window.onload function, with the default being grey and after 10s changing to red?

Comment: Yes, and even better why don't you make the circle gray from the beginning, I mean in your HTML code, is there any reason?, and then you just use one setTimeout to change it after 10 seconds, and that makes it the easy and simple way to do that

Answer (score 1):

You could use this when the page loads:

```
async function set_colors(){
    get_color(grey); //Get the color and do what you need to do;
    await sleep(10000);  //Call function "Sleep" and wait 10000ms(10s)
    get_color(red);//Get the color and do what you need to do;
    
}

function sleep(ms) {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="set_colors();">
```

Comment: but setTimeout runs async so the get_color(red) is not gonna wait, but execute instantly instead, and that makes your answer wrong